# How can I setup Visual Studio Code(VSC) or Sublime Text3 to run ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio-code, sublimetext3, jsx

I am new with ReactJS. I tried VSC and Sublime Text3 as my IDE. My OS is Windows 10, I installed NodeJS, Babel and added {"type": "module"} in package.json file. I cannot run or build JSX syntax. Below is a simple JSX file.

```
import React from 'react';

const Footer = () => {
    return(
        <footer>
        this is my footer
        </footer>
        );
}
export default Footer;
```

When I run(build with node in sublime) this I receive an error, please help setup my IDE.

```
ExperimentalWarning: The ESM module loader is experimental.
file:///D:/myreact/src/components/Footer.js:6
        <footer>
        ^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'
    at Loader.moduleStrategy (internal/modules/esm/translators.js:88:18)
    at async link (internal/modules/esm/module_job.js:41:21)
```

Below is my package.json

```
{
  "name": "myreact",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "type": "module",
  "dependencies": {
    "cra-template": "1.0.3",
    "react": "^16.13.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.13.1",
    "react-scripts": "3.4.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

Here is a screenshot of my sublime
[image]

Comment: Did you setup your project using `create-react-app`? Please show your `package.json` in your question.

Comment: Yes, I used create-react-app. See Package.json above, thank you.

Comment: @LiuYu What happens when you run `npm start`?

Comment: it's weird actually, I just tested your code including the `package.json` and I can run it successfully. have you tried to just save it and run `npm start` from console?

Comment: When I run npm start, there is a window pops up, and react works fine. It is just in the console or terminal, I cannot run the JSX code, anything I did wrong here?

Comment: Is it because I don't have a JSX compiler? JS does not understand <footer> in the function. How can I add a compiler to my IDE? I googled a lot, no luck.

Comment: are all the dependencies installed? have you run `npm install` yet?

Comment: Yes, I have. Same result. Do I need a compiler?

Comment: When you say *It is just in the console or terminal, I cannot run the JSX code* what do you mean? Are you running it in console using `node Footer.js` ?

Comment: Or you may be using `F7` to build it, If you are doing that then I can't understand why you need to do it because all it does is run a single file. A react project doesn't require you to build/execute a single file.

Comment: This is an example jsx file, sometimes I need to run console.log to see what prints in terminal(command or console), that's why I run or build. I did 'npm start' in my terminal, the page loads.

Comment: @Liu Yu The output of console.log can be seen in the console window of browser in which you are running your application. There is no need to run a file separately.